# How can I render partial in a coffee script filter, with haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

How can I render a partial with haml and rails?
This is my code.

```
   :coffee
      $(document).ready ->
        $('#addBelteri').click ->
          $('div#belterik').append( #{ = render('belteri, :belteriClickCounter => window.belteriClickCounter) } )
          window.belteriClickCounter++
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `escape_javascript`

```
$('div#belterik').append("#{ escape_javascript render('belteri, :belteriClickCounter => window.belteriClickCounter)}")
```

which is also aliased as 'j' so you can have:

```
$('div#belterik').append("#{ j render('belteri', :belteriClickCounter => window.belteriClickCounter)}")
```